# How to connect to IBM Cloud Redis from Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, ibm-cloud, sidekiq

Migrating from one service to IBM Cloud for Redis.

I cannot find the correct configuration to connect using TLS.  Everything I find on this is related to Heroku. and it ignores verifying the TLS/SSL connection.

I cannot find how to configure our Sidekiq/Redis to connect.

I do have a certificate from the IBM Cloud dashboard and I suspect I have to pass that along somehow.

Configure the Sidekiq.yml like this

```
:redis:
    :url: "rediss://:< PWD >@< DB Name >:< PORT >/0"
    :namespace: "app"
    :ssl_params:
      ca_file: 'path/to/cert'
```

I keep getting back the error `Redis::CommandError - WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair or user is disabled.:` however using these same credentials in the migration script I am able to connect to the DB, so the credentials are ok, I think it is not including the certificate correctly and I cannot find the correct way to do this

Answer (score 0):

The sidekiq.yml configuration looks good to me, just make sure this has correct complete path

> ca_file: 'path/to/cert'

and change the redis url to

> :url: "rediss://< PWD >@< DB Name >:< PORT >/0"

further info you can read from [here](https://redis.io/docs/management/security/encryption/) for TLS secured connection.

Comment: Ya still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: i removed that colon symbol, was expecting it to work. will update if i find something

Comment: ya with it or without it, same error

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with sidekiq.yml.  But I've configured redlin with redis using a python script you can find here: https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/vpc-transit/blob/master/py/test_transit.py.  Maybe the configuration is similar.

The relevant code is:

```
def vpe_redis_test(fip, resource):
    """execute a command in fip to verify postgresql is accessible"""
    redis = resource["key"]
    credentials = redis["credentials"]
    cert_data = credentials["connection.rediss.certificate.certificate_base64"]
    cli_arguments = credentials["connection.cli.arguments.0.1"]
    command = f""" 
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
if [ -x ./redli ]; then
  echo redli already installed
else
  curl -LO https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/redli/releases/download/v0.5.2/redli_0.5.2_linux_amd64.tar.gz
  tar zxvf redli_*_linux_amd64.tar.gz
fi
./redli \
  --long \
  -u {cli_arguments} \
  --certb64={cert_data} << TEST > redis.out
  set foo working
```

Comment: I'm totally open to tryng anything, but how would I use this in place of what I have?